# stderr: fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/master

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have created a Jenkins pipeline for my project. I am having issue with the `git checkout` stage.

Below is the error:

```
stderr: fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/master
```

Error Screenshot:

[image]

Help me with the proper solution to solve this error. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the same issue here.
the branch name in GitHub had changed to "main". So, you need to change the branch Specifier on Jenkins as the following:

your project on Jenkins/"Configuration"/"Pipeline"/"Branches to build"/"Branch Specifier" -> changed to "*/main" (it was "*/master")

then problem solved

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check your GitHub branch name is correct or not.

It is saying "remote ref refs/heads/master" branch is not the right one.